# Can't update state using useState and axios response with array

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to update the state of my component with useState, using data received with axios. The problem is that "setCursos" doesn't update "cursos", which starts as an empty array. I have tried a lot of things but none of them seems to work. Please help. This is what a have so far:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const CursosAdmin = (props) => {
    const [cursos, setCursos] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('/api/cursos')
            .then(res => {
                setCursos(cursos => [...cursos, res.data]);  
                console.log(cursos);
            })
    }, []);

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>pagina de admin</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default CursosAdmin;
```

and this is what I have in express:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const cursosData = require('../jsonFiles/cursosData.json');

let listaCursos = cursosData.cursos;

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(listaCursos);

    res.send(listaCursos);
    res.status(200);
});

module.exports = router;
```

aaand the json file where I'm getting the data:

```
{
    "cursos": [
        {
            "id_curso": 0,
            "curso_nombre": "IPC2",
            "secciones": [],
            "universidad": "Universidad de San Carlos de Guatemala" 
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is `res.data`? Is it array? If so, you may need to spread it `setCursos(cursos => [...cursos, ...res.data]);`

Comment: Hi Noah, can you please share jsonFiles/cursosData.json snippet so can see the data structure and update the data into the state accordingly?

Comment: and before updating the state you must try to console.log('Response: ', res) so we could be confirmed that what data we are getting from the axios!

Comment: I tried console.log(res) and "data" throws the array that comes from my json file, but for some reason when I try to update the state with that array is still empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('/api/cursos')
            .then(res => {
                setCursos([...cursos, res.data]);  
            })
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this instead:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get('/api/cursos')
        .then(res => {
            setCursos([...cursos, res.data]);  
            console.log(cursos);
        })
}, []);
```

As stated on the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-what-do-square-brackets-mean) for React Hooks, the function that updates the state takes in a parameter which updates the state itself, hence there is no need to pass an additional function within your `setCursos` method in order to update your state.

Answer (score 1):

I think that It dosen't route precise. 
So, I change this path `/` -> `/api/cursos`

```
// fix route path 
router.get('/api/cursos', (req, res) => {
    console.log(listaCursos);

    res.send(listaCursos);
    res.status(200);
});
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for your answer!